# Checking for module availability programmatically in Python?

Tags: python, module, python-module

given a list of module names (e.g. mymods = ['numpy', 'scipy', ...]) how can I check if the modules are available?

I tried the following but it's incorrect:

```
for module_name in mymods:
  try:
    import module_name
  except ImportError:
    print "Module %s not found." %(module_name)
```

thanks.

Comment: @wRAR: Because "os = 'sys'; import os" tries to import os, not sys.

Comment: Why do you want to check rather than just importing the modules and letting the default mechanism do its thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use both the `__import__` function, as in @Vinay's answer, **and** a `try`/`except`, as in your code:

```
for module_name in mymods:
  try:
    __import__(module_name)
  except ImportError:
    print "Module %s not found." %(module_name)
```

Alternatively, to **just** check availability but **without** actually loading the module, you can use standard library module [imp](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html?highlight=imp#module-imp):

```
import imp
for module_name in mymods:
  try:
    imp.find_module(module_name)
  except ImportError:
    print "Module %s not found." %(module_name)
```

this can be substantially faster if you **do** only want to check for availability, not (yet) load the modules, especially for modules that take a while to load.  Note, however, that this second approach only specifically checks that **the modules** are there -- it doesn't check for the availability of any further modules that might be required (because the modules being checked try to `import` other modules when they load).  Depending on your exact specs, this might be a plus or a minus!-)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `__import__` function:

```
>>> for mname in ('sys', 'os', 're'): __import__(mname)
...
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
<module 'os' from 'C:\Python\lib\os.pyc'>
<module 're' from 'C:\Python\lib\re.pyc'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, more than 10 years after the question, in Python >= 3.4, the way to go is using [`importlib.util.find_spec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec):

```py
import importlib
spec = importlib.util.find_spec('path.to.module')
if spam:
    print('module can be imported')
```

This mechanism is them [preferred over `imp.find_module`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37260391/2989289):

````py
import importlib.util
import sys


# this is optional set that if you what load from specific directory
moduledir="d:\\dirtest"

```python
try:
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec('path.to.module', moduledir)
    if spec is None:
        print("Import error 0: " + " module not found")
        sys.exit(0)
    toolbox = spec.loader.load_module()
except (ValueError, ImportError) as msg:
    print("Import error 3: "+str(msg))
    sys.exit(0)

print("load module")
````

For old Python versions also look [how to check if a python module exists without importing it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37260391/2989289)

Answer (score 0):

In recent Python versions (>= 3.4), `importlib.util.module_from_spec('foo')` will return `None` if `foo` cannot be imported, in other words, unavilable.
This check will not actually import the module.

```
import importlib.util
if importlib.util.find_spec('foo') is None:
    # module foo cannot be imported
    pass
else:
    # module foo can be imported
    pass
```

More info:

1. `importlib.util.module_from_spec` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec)
2. [Sample code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#checking-if-a-module-can-be-imported) to import a module after checking that 1) it has not been imported yet; and 2) it can be imported.