# What is the equivalent of imp.find_module in importlib

Tags: python, python-3.x

Some of my code use the now deprecated *imp* package to find a module

```
toolboxFile, toolboxPath, toolboxDescription = imp.find_module("Tools")
```

What is the equivalent function or code to get the same results with package *importlib* ?

Answer (score 17):

#### Same folder

If the module is in your working directory, [`importlib.util.find_spec`](http://docs.python.org/3.6/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec) probably suffices for your purposes.

For example if you just want to load the module, you can use:

- **deprecated in Python 3.5 and higher:**

  ```
  toolbox_specs = importlib.util.find_spec("Tools")
  toolbox = toolbox_specs.loader.load_module()
  ```
- **introduced in Python 3.5 and higher:**

  ```
  toolbox_specs = importlib.util.find_spec("Tools")
  toolbox = importlib.util.module_from_spec(toolbox_specs)
  toolbox_specs.loader.exec_module(toolbox)
  ```

  *Caveat: I haven’t tested this, but it’s straight from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.6/library/importlib.html#examples), so I suppose it works.*

You can assess several other properties with the `toolbox_specs` object.
However, e.g., a corresponding file object is not amongst them.
If you really need this in Python 3, you probably have to obtain the file’s path and open it with other methods.

#### Different folder

To find a module in a different folder, you have to work with a [`FileFinder`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.FileFinder), which in turn needs to know the module’s type. For example, if your module is an extension, you can find the specs as follows:

```
loader_details = (
    importlib.machinery.ExtensionFileLoader,
    importlib.machinery.EXTENSION_SUFFIXES
    )

toolsfinder = importlib.machinery.FileFinder("Folder_of_Tools", loader_details)
toolbox_specs = toolsfinder.find_spec("Tools")
```

You can then process `toolbox_specs` as described above.

Comment: If `Tools` does an implicit sibling import (e.g. `import foo` and there is a `foo.py` file along side `Tools.py`), this solution yields `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'`. Any way to address this?

Comment: @PedroCattori: I am not entirely sure what your situation is, let allone how to address it. I suggest you ask a separate question on this.

Comment: You have to use importlib.util.module_from_spec(toolbox_specs) the infamous toolbox_specs.loader.load_module() does not work if you have relative import in the loaded module like "from . import myModule", all you get is the amazing "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package". The python foundation should really get their act together...

Answer (score 13):

I found this worked as a replacement for imp.find_module()

```
importlib.machinery.PathFinder().find_spec(mod_name, module_dir_list)
```

Comment: What is provided as modDirList?

Comment: "module Directory List" if I remember the naming convention on that example. It was a list of strings where each string was a particular directory containing the modules we are trying to find.  Basically it's the path.

Answer (score -1):

According to Python official documentation in this page [imp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.find_module)

`find_module` Deprecated since version 3.3 Use `importlib.util.find_spec()` instead unless Python 3.3 compatibility is required, in which case use `importlib.find_loader()`.

Use  `importlib.util.find_spec("Tools")` for find spec for more information you can see this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec).

And use  `importlib.find_loader("Tools")` for find loader [more information](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.find_loader)

**EDIT:**

sample code

```
import importlib
import importlib.util
import sys

    name="test"
    moduledir="d:\\dirtest"
# this is optional set that if you what load from specific directory
    try:
        spec = importlib.util.find_spec(name,moduledir)
        if spec is None:
            print("Import error 0: " + " module not found")
            sys.exit(0)
        toolbox = spec.loader.load_module()
    except (ValueError, ImportError) as msg:
        print("Import error 3: "+str(msg))
        sys.exit(0)

    print("load module")
```

Comment: Can you address whether and how any of these commands allows you to find modules in a different path than the working path?

Comment: Your example code does not work for me if `moduledir` is not the current directory (also the indentation is broken), even if there is a module in that directory that would be found otherwise. Does it work for you? If yes, we may have found a bug. If no, we either have a bug or misunderstood how it works.

Comment: Yes it works for me version test with python version 3.4.4

Comment: As it stands, this code does not work and is not intended to do so. [`find_spec`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec) does not take a directory as second argument. The variant with `find_loader` should not have worked either, as this takes a list of directiories and not a directory as an argument.